# Split binary file to two files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not very familiar with python but having to g to write a script for spiting binary into two other file. The first file should take every 1st byte and second file should take every 2nd byte. I've written the following script, but somehow all the output files are zeros.
Can you please help?

```
from pip._vendor.msgpack.fallback import xrange

filePath = sys.argv[1]
yuv_string_bytes = bytes(open(filePath, 'rb').read())

file_uv = open("uv_buffer", "wb+")
file_y = open("y_buffer", "wb+")
for i in xrange(0, len(yuv_string_bytes), 2):
    uv = bytes(yuv_string_bytes[i])
    y = bytes(yuv_string_bytes[i+1])
    file_uv.write(uv)
    file_y.write(y)

file_y.close()
file_uv.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much simpler

```
yuv_string_bytes = bytes(open(filePath, 'rb').read())

with open("uv_buffer", "wb+") as f:
  f.write(yuv_string_bytes[::2])
with open("y_buffer", "wb+") as f:
  f.write(yuv_string_bytes[1::2])
```

Comment: The `bytes()` is pretty superfluous…

Comment: maybe, I copypasted it from question

Answer (score 1):

The most memory efficient way is to read the input file byte by byte and write that byte to the other files in turn:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as yuv, \
        open('uv_buffer', 'wb') as uv, open('y_buffer', 'wb') as y:
    while True:
        b = yuv.read(2)
        if not b:
            break
        uv.write(b[:1])
        v.write(b[1:])
```

This only ever stores two bytes in memory at once, as compared to your reading the entire file into memory. You can read larger chunks at a time (say, `1024`, or `1024 * 1024`) and distribute them to the two files from there, depending on your preferred tradeoff between CPU/IO and memory optimisation:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as yuv, \
        open('uv_buffer', 'wb') as uv, open('y_buffer', 'wb') as y:
    while True:
        b = yuv.read(1024)
        if not b:
            break
        uv.write(b[::2])
        y.write(b[1::2])
```

Comment: its tooooooo slow. For large files, you can read it by blocks of several megabytes then use slice way from another solution

Comment: Yeah, that's true, each individual read operation probably has too much overhead. This is the most *memory* efficient way I should say. Where exactly the best tradeoff lies between memory and CPU efficiency OP has to figure out for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The problem where you're going wrong is that bytes(n) constructs a byte object of size n (with all values set to 0x00). I would change this from:

```
uv = bytes(yuv_string_bytes[i])
y = bytes(yuv_string_bytes[i+1])
```

to:

```
uv = yuv_string_bytes[i].to_bytes(1, 'big')
y = yuv_string_bytes[i+1].to_bytes(1, 'big')
```

But like others have said, your implementation is not the best way to go about this. Python has a lot of features to help with such string & data manipulation.